# Separation theorem on the space of all complex continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C$ be the Banach space of all complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with the supremum norm. Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $C$. Does there exist a $\Lambda\in C^*$ for which $\Lambda (B)$ is open?

Note that $C$ is a locally convex space and $B$ is convex, balanced and closed set, by the separation theorem of convex sets,we know there exists $\Lambda\in C^*$ such that $|\Lambda f|\leq 1$ for all $f\in B$ and $|\Lambda f|>1$ for $f\in B^c$. But how about this when we consider some concrete space above?

Answer (score 4):

Take

$$\Lambda(f) = \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\, dt.$$

$\Lambda(B) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert < 1\}$ can be verified with a little computation.

> by the separation theorem of convex sets,we know there exists $\Lambda\in C^*$ such that $|\Lambda f|\leq 1$ for all $f\in B$ and $|\Lambda f|>1$ for $f\in B^c$

No, the complement $B^c$ of $B$ is not convex, so it cannot be separated from $B$ by a linear functional (every linear functional takes the value $0$ both in $B$ and $B^c$).

Comment: That's my wrong,I just want to say $|\Lambda f|>1$ if $f$ is not in $B$.But how can I know the representation of a concrete functional,such as the continuous linear functional on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and on general Banach space?

Comment: If you have a convex (compact or open) set $D$ with $D\cap B = \varnothing$, then you can find a $\Lambda$ with $\Lambda(B) \subset \{\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\}$ and $\Re \Lambda(f) > 1$ for all $f \in D$. But not for the complement $B^c$. The representation of continuous linear functionals is in general a difficult question. For Hilbert spaces (like $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$), all continuous linear functionals are given by $f \mapsto \langle f\mid g\rangle$ (taking the inner product linear in the first and antilinear in the second argument). For $C$, it's the space of complex Borel measures.

Comment: I think What you say of the last sentence is the Riesz representative theorem.But when I come  to verify some statements about weak convergence I need the concrete functional,that's a confusion for me.

Comment: Something to your answer:for any $f\in B$,we have $||f||=sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|\leq 1$,and $|\Lambda f|\leq |\int^{1/2}_0 f(t)dt|+|\int^1_{1/2}f(t)dt|\leq \int^1_0 |f(t)|dt\leq 1.$ Sorry,I haven't got the result.

Comment: Prove that a) You can't get the value $1$, but b) you can come arbitrarily close to it. The remainder follows by rotation as $\Lambda(e^{i\varphi}f) = e^{i\varphi}\Lambda(f)$. So you can restrict yourself to real-valued functions. If a real-valued function $f$ with $\lvert f\rvert \leqslant 1$ had $\int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt = 1$, can it be continuous?

Comment: Yes,no matter it were be,there would not hold $\int^{1/2}_0(f(t)-1)dt=\int^1_{1/2}(f(t)+1)dt$.